# Executing generated script from output

Tags: oracle

I created a script that generates and outputs the required `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION` commands that I need to execute.

**main script:** (without all the conditions, for better use here in SE)

```
SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '||CHR(39)|| ao.SID ||',' || ao.SERIAL# ||CHR(39) || ' IMMEDIATE;' 
FROM v$session ao where (length(trim(ao.username)) = 5 
                and upper(substr(trim(ao.username),1,1)) = 'E'
```

**output example:**

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '418,30413' IMMEDIATE;                                                                         
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '755,19371' IMMEDIATE;                                                                         
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '809,6715' IMMEDIATE;
```

How can I execute the generated `ALTER`s ?

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.0.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd copy and paste the commands and then run them.  If you want to do this in a single step, you can write a small PL/SQL block

```
BEGIN
  FOR s IN (SELECT *
              FROM v$session ao 
             where (length(trim(ao.username)) = 5 
               and upper(substr(trim(ao.username),1,1)) = 'E')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '||
                         CHR(39)|| s.SID ||',' || s.SERIAL# ||CHR(39) || 
                         ' IMMEDIATE';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  SQL Developer you can use SQL*Plus. This allows you to generate statements and execute them. Execute

```
sqlplus user/password@tnsname @script.sql
```

where script has the following content:

```
spool statements.sql
set pagesize 0
set feedback off

set linesize 300
set trimout on
set trimspool on

SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '||CHR(39)|| ao.SID ||',' 
  || ao.SERIAL# ||CHR(39) || ' IMMEDIATE;' 
FROM v$session ao where (length(trim(ao.username)) = 5 
  and upper(substr(trim(ao.username),1,1)) = 'E'
/
spool off
spool statements.log
set feedback
@statements.sql
spool off
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this button - it executes the output as as script.

[image: Run Script Output As Script: The Movie]